# Syntax highlighting: default to JavaScript highlighting for questions tagged [javascript-automation] / [jxa]

Tags: discussion, feature-request, syntax-highlighting

[JXA (JavaScript for Automation)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/Articles/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014508-CH111-SW1), as the name implies, is based on a single language, JavaScript, so it makes sense to apply JavaScript highlighting to code blocks by default.

P.S.: Perhaps introducing a general [syntax-highlighting-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax-highlighting-request) tag makes sense to facilitate such requests in the future.

Comment: Combining [meta-tag:feature-request] and [meta-tag:syntax-highlighting] makes having a [meta-tag:syntax-highlighting-request] redundant.

Comment: @TinyGiant: I see your point, but having a _single_ tag following the pattern of tags such as [tag:retag-request], [tag:synonym-request], and [tag:burninate-request] is both convenient and more specific.

Comment: Well, I could see where you might think that, but technically your question is a feature request about syntax highlighting. Meaning there is already a tag combination that is perfectly usable. And [if you take a look at this query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=newest&tags=feature-request%20syntax-highlighting&mode=all&pageSize=50) you'll notice that this combination is already in use on many questions on the topic, so it would be best to just use what has been used up to this point

Comment: @TinyGiant: That link is broken for me (lack of privileges on my end?). Either way, I wouldn't base an argument on "it would be best to just use what has been used up to this point" - it's never too late to improve an existing practice.

Comment: Oh, sorry that's a new nav link, well anyways there is a whole bunch of questions that use that combination of tags.

Comment: @TinyGiant I've added [tag:feature-request] to this answer for now, but let me make one last argument (and I think we can leave it at that): Semantically, the combination of tags [tag:feature-request] and [tag:syntax-highlighting] is still more _generic_ than _specifically_ asking to have specific syntax-highlighting turned on for a given tag. Setting aside a distinct tag for the latter, _repeating_ type of request, especially following an existing pattern, strikes me as beneficial.
P.S.: What's a new nav link?

Comment: The new nav is an experimental opt-in feature that the devs rolled out a couple months back. There's a post on Meta Meta about it somewhere. I'm killing zombies right now or I would go find the reference for you.

Comment: Here's the non-new-nav version of @TinyGiant's link: [Questions tagged feature-request and syntax-highlighting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+syntax-highlighting)