# Default syntax highlighting for [reactjs] tag

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

I noticed a question with `reactjs` tag without the `javascript` tag and it does not have any default syntax highlighting: [ReactJS - How to properly initialize state from props which is populated by fetching data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38815191/reactjs-how-to-properly-initialize-state-from-props-which-is-populated-by-fetc) (might get editted though...)

I did not find a way how to suggest adding a default syntax highlighting for the tag directly on https://stackoverflow.com/tags/reactjs/info

Also a similar question [Syntax highlighting: default to JavaScript highlighting for questions tagged [javascript-automation] / [jxa]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307988/syntax-highlighting-default-to-javascript-highlighting-for-questions-tagged-ja) was not answered, so not sure if META is the right place for suggesting this, just the only place I can think of :)

**Can we add `js` syntax to the `reactjs` tag?**

Or perhaps all tags matching `/js$/` and their synonyms?